# Which volume of novel or chapter of manga should I read next in Chrome Shelled Regios?

Tags: chrome-shelled-regios

I finished watching *Chrome Shelled Regios* a while ago. I'm  now planning to read the light novel or manga. Having watched the anime, which volume (of the light novel) or chapter (of the manga) should I start at?

Comment: I believe The anime ends at about vol. 7, chapter 2 of the light novel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Krazer notes in his comment, the anime adapts the novel up to [volume 7, chapter 2](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=30048). So you should start from chapter 3. There are 24 volumes in all.